# Mathematical Reasoning for Solving Integer Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima, integer-programming

For an integer programming problem, I found that using the integer programming function intlinprog in matlab (based on branch and bound) is the same as using simple mathematical reasoning. For the following problem:
$$min \  Cx-Ay $$
$$s.t. \ x+y \le 150$$
$$ \ \ 0\le x \le 100$$
$$ \ \ 0\le y \le 100$$
Where A is a constant greater than $0$ and greater than C.

For this problem, we should set $y=100$. Then, if C>=$0$, we should set $x=0$, otherwise $x$ is $50$.

I want to know what mathematical method I use to analyze in this way? Why does it produce the same result as the integer programming (Branch and bound) method?

Another problem is if I first solve the following integer program:
$$min \  Cx-Ay $$
$$s.t. 0\le x \le 100$$
$$ \ \ 0\le y \le 100$$
Now, i can get $x$ and $y$. Then I add condition $ x+y \le 150$ to further solve for $x$ and $y$. How is this solver different from the integer program solver above?

Comment: You essentially solved the linear problem by analyzing some/most vertices of the feasible polytope. One could argue that maybe you used some extremely simple version of the simplex algorithm. You were also lucky in that you started from a problem with zero integrality gap, where the solution to the LP relaxation is already integral.